# nginx local redirect from /var/www/html/index.html to /var/www/html/larvel_project/public

Tags: nginx, laravel-6.2

we are working on a local WIFI project where we use internet-enabled **Ubuntu** server inside **CPU** and we don't have any domain name to point it. We provide wifi access from the CPU server so that anyone can access it within our local premises.

For captive portal working, we need to have **generate_204** folder inside the following

**/var/www/html/generate_204/**

from here we redirect to **index.php** which is at the same level of **generate_204** folder as following

**/var/www/html/index.php**

from here I want to redirect to my Laravel project folder which resides inside the same level as following

**/var/www/html/laravel_project/public/**

The overall structure is as follows

```
/var/www/html/
            index.php
            generate_204/
                        index.php
            laravel_project/
                           public/
                                 index.php
```

How can I achieve redirection from **/var/www/html/index.php** to **/var/www/html/laravel_project/public/**

Following is my current NGINX setup:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;
    server_name _;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

The above NGINX setup works fine when we had a plain PHP project and we were redirecting.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: And how are you redirecting ? Using the `header("Location: ....")` in PHP ? What value exactly are you using for each of the locations ?

Comment: Yes I am using header("Location") along with some get parameters like header("Location: index.php?wd=XYZ&mac=XYZ&ip_address=XYZ");

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a need to redirect to your laravel folder. Just change the line 
`root /var/www/html;` to `root /var/www/html/laravel_project/public;`

also i have

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Yup tried even now its redirecting properly. Let me check with new instance